# onclick window will not trigger if a specific cookie exits

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not much experience much in javascript. Recently i am trying to learn and implement popunder onclick. Its working perfectly for me but unfortunately every time open a popunder window when i am click the body.

I want to handle something like:

> Create a cookie on first time onclick
>   second time if will be check if cookie exists or not

In this way only one time popunder window will open

Here is the Index code

```
    <html onclick='pop("https://www.google.com",null,{
      "point":"uid",
      "postback":"doha"
    }).under()'>

<script>
window.onerror = function(msg, url, linenumber) {
    alert('Error message: '+msg+'\nURL: '+url+'\nLine Number: '+linenumber);
    return true;
}
</script>
<script src="POPPage.js"></script>
<script>
pop().postbackHandler({
  doha:()=>{

  }
})

</script>
POPUnder
</html>
```

I have other two js file but security reason not sharing this

Can anyone help me to solve this.As i am beginner

Comment: So let me get this straight you want to create a cookie the first time and then the second time - if there is a cookie you execuet the pop("url....").under() command?

Comment: There is a nice library here for making/readign etc cookies https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie use that to assist

Comment: Not really, First time onclick event should prompt as it is but i want to not fired it second time.Thats way my idea is to write cookie on first time so second time on click will not executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to figure out what it is your trying to do.
But something simple like this would work.

You'll need to replace the alert with whatever it is your trying to run.

```
<html >

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@rc/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script src="POPPage.js"></script>
<script>

function mycode() {


    if(Cookies.get('nameofcookie') == undefined) {

        pop("https://localjs.blogspot.com",null,{
  "point":"uid",
  "postback":"doha"
}).under()


        Cookies.set('nameofcookie', '1')

    }


}

pop().postbackHandler({
  doha:()=>{
    alert("got postback")
  }
})

</script>

<body style="background-color:#FF0000" onclick="mycode()">

<p>something</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @shahed ok here you go. So it just does it the once.